# How to create 2 headers in a panda dataframe, and also add an image to this header?

Tags: python, pandas

I hope you're doing well !

I've a pd dataframe, with one row for a header, but I'd like to add a new header in the first row) and the second row is the current header.

How Can I do That ?

For the moment, I've created this dataframe:

```
devis= pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Code_complet' ,'Article', 'DN' ,'Caractéristiques' ,'Nuance' ,'Intitulé_complet',"Quantité",'Poids', 'Diamètre' ,'Epaisseur'])
```

So the header are the name of these columns.

But I'd like to add a new header, above these columns, these new columns will be :
-The image ( so How can I add in image in a header ???)

- The date
  -The Object
- The place
- A short description

Thanks in advance guys !!! :)

Comment: You simply can't add image in the header of a data frame.

Comment: alright ! And how to create another header ?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html